# Swift Sodium - Anonymous Encryption (Sealed Boxes)

Tags: swift, libsodium

I am trying to encrypt value using swift sodium with given public key.
However, the encrypted value is not the same as what's produced on server side.
I am not sure whether this piece of coding is right in swift.
The steps are similar to how its done in java.

Assume public key is in base64 string format.

Java:

```
String pubKey = "w6mjd11n9w9ncKfcuR888Ygi02ou+46ocIajlcUEmQ="; 
String secret = "hithere"
byte[] pubKeyBytes = Base64.decode(pubKey,0);
SealedBox sealedDeal = new SealedBox(pubKeyBytes);
byte[] c = sealedDeal.encrypt(secret.getBytes());
String ciphertext = Base64.encodeToString(c, 0);
```

Swift:

```
let pubKey = "w6mjd11n9w9ncKfcuR888Ygi02ou+46ocIajlcUEmQ="
let dataDecoded:NSData = NSData(base64Encoded: pubKey, options: NSData.Base64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))!
let secret = "hithere".toData()!
let c : Data = sodium.box.seal(message: secret, recipientPublicKey: dataDecoded as Box.PublicKey)!
let ciphertext = c.base64EncodedString(options: .init(rawValue: 0))
```

Please tell me know what's wrong with the swift equivalent coding. 
Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

The encrypted value is supposed to be different, so that ciphertexts resulting from equivalent plaintexts are indistinguishable (see [Ciphertext indistinguishability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_indistinguishability)).

Answer (score 0):

`sodium.box.seal` internally generates new `nonce` every time you are encrypting message, @Max is right, this is normal behave

You can use `Detached mode` to give same nonce, but this is a very bad idea

In your example you have used `Anonymous Encryption` I suggest you to take a look at [Authenticated Encryption](https://github.com/jedisct1/swift-sodium#authenticated-encryption)